# ContentControl.Template is null even it is in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

Maybe title is confusing you, but the problem is concretely here : I have `XAML` file which there is `ControlTemplate` for `MyType` (inherits from `ContentControl`). And in that `Template` i set its `DataContext` like this :

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

And when i want to get `DataContext` from `MyType` it shows null for first time. After clicking on it ( it is rectangle in window ) it changes to object what i need. I searched all things, all events what i am doing in `LeftButtonDown` there is no `ApplyTemplate(),UpdateLayout()` methods. Even i call these methods it doesn't help. What need to do ? P.S this `DataContext` is `Parent` of this item, i can send is a parameter but there must be other solution

this is part of `XAML` which Template located:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:Connector}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:Connector}">
                <Grid Name="grid" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
                        Path=BorderBrush}" x:Name="border" BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent">        
                        <Image Source="/DiagramDesigner;component/Resources/1337238611_port.png"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Margin="-2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is where i want to get DataContext:

```
public DesignerItem ParentDesignerItem // 
    {
        get
        {

            if (parentDesignerItem == null)
            {

                parentDesignerItem = this.DataContext as DesignerItem;
               // if (parentDesignerItem==null) parentDesignerItem = (this.Template.FindName("grid", this) as Grid).DataContext as DesignerItem;
            }

            return parentDesignerItem;
        }
        set
        {

            parentDesignerItem = value;
        }
    }
```

I must say that this `Style` is in `XAML` which `Style` of the `DesignerItem` also.

Comment: I think you should post more code for us to understand your question.

Comment: Dude your English sucks. I'm trying to wrap my head around this question and help you but you have to make an effort too. You sad something about clicking on element maybe you have a click handler that sets this style to control or triggers change that sets this style. Why did you declare style that sets template and not only a template?

Comment: Problem is that: i have click handler, and i set IsSelected to true, and no other things. I have other things in style i cut them because there is no need to show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in my algorithm P.S i restore some information from `SQL`, and add 2 times more `Connectors` with null parameters and when i want to access it gives me these null objects.